# How to find the Lyapunov function for the following system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

How to find the Lyapunov function for the following ODE system
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= ax - x^3 + y\\
\dot{y} &= x^3
\end{align}
where $a$ is just a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Lyapunov functions will be "bowl-shaped", i.e. even powered in spatial variables. For a Lyapunov function $L(x,y)$, solution trajectories are decreasing, i.e.
$$
\frac{d}{dt}L(x(t),y(t))=\nabla L(x(t),y(t))\cdot(\dot{x},\dot{y})=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}L(x(t),y(t))\dot{x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}L(x(t),y(t))\dot{y} < 0
$$

One usually tries Lyapunov functions of the form $L(x,y)=\alpha x^m + \beta y^n$ and picks $\alpha$, $\beta$, $m$ and $n$ to make the time derivative negative-definite. Try this Lyapunov function in your case and pick the correct exponents to make everything negative-definite.

The condition that $dL/dt$ be negative definite can be weakened by requireing that $dL/dt$ be negative definite almost everywhere that you care about.

Edit:

This function does not have any corresponding Lyapunov functions. Linearizing around the sole fixed point at $(0,0)$ gives degenerate stability. Graphical analysis (or numerical simulation) shows that the origin is always unstable for any value of $a$. Hence, there is no stability candidate for a Lyapunov function and analysis via a Lyapunov function is not a valid strategy here.

Existence of a Lyapunov function is a method for extending the stability of a fixed point from a neighborhood in which linear stability analysis is valid to a larger region, and potentially globally.

Comment: I tried this form, but seems like I can't find anything. Is it possible that there are some other complicated combinations?

Comment: Are you sure there **is** a Lyapunov function? For $a=\pm 1$ you won't be able to find one since there are no stable fixed points or limit cycles.

Comment: Update: There will not be a Lyapunov function here. The origin is the only fixed point and it has degenerate stability. Graphical analysis shows it is always unstable. Hence there cannot be a Lyapunov function. It is a good idea to always do linear stability analysis first. You must have a stable fixed point to get a Lyapunov function.

Comment: Can I prove the fixed point is unstable by showing $\dot{V}>0$ (suppose $V$ is the Lyap func)?

Comment: No. Going this route you must prove something much much stronger, namely that for all functions $V:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\dot{V}>0$, since converse statement about existence is "for all". Strictly speaking a Lyapunov function is one for which $\dot{V}<0$, so saying that $\dot{V}>0$ for all Lyapunov functions doesn't make sense. Lyapunov is a way to extend the notion of stability, and cannot say anything about instability.

Comment: That makes sense. I am wondering is there any other way to analyze the stability of this system? It seems to me the linearization won't work. Of course I can always turn to numerical solution, but I am just curious about if there is some other ways.

Comment: You can prove the origin is linearly unstable even though it is degenerate by looking at the eigenvalues. For global stability it is harder, but if you rule out limit cycles and there is a single unstable fixed point than you know that the system is globally unstable.

Comment: If there exists $V$ s.t. $V(0) = 0$ and $V > 0, \dot V >0$ in a punctured neighborhood of $0$, that proves that $0$ is unstable. Sometimes this $V$ is also called a Lyapunov function. There is also a stronger statement, which considers only a part of the neighborhood.